# How do I get a Rust Command to actually output to stdout?

Tags: rust, process, stdout

I am trying to use Command::process to spawn some processes and to get started I want to check I can get a simple command like `echo` to work correctly. I want to take some user input and then spawn a process to echo this back to stdout, so that I can verify that I get a response like:

```
> echo this!
echo this!    <-- my echoed text
```

Currently, I am trying to do this like this:

```
use std::io;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut some_input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut some_input)
        .unwrap();

    let command_example = Command::new("echo")
        .arg(&some_input)
        .output()
        .unwrap();

    let expected_output = format!("{}\n", &some_input);

    assert_eq!(expected_output.as_bytes(), command_example.stdout.as_slice());
}
```

The `assert` block is passing, so I can see that the output of the command ends up in the struct's stout buffer. However, when I run this in the terminal, there is no output, the program just ends without printing anything back to stdout. What am I doing wrong that this code doesn't result in something being printed to the stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output):

> Executes the command as a child process, waiting for it to finish and collecting all of its output.

Thus, you obtain all the standard output of the process in your `command_example` variable.
Nothing appears in the terminal, because this was collected.

Alternatively, instead of `.output()`, you can use [`.status()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status) in order to run the process without capturing its standard output; it will then show up in the terminal.